# util-linux's getopt ignores first argument

Tags: command-line, arguments

I followed the posts on stackexchange websites to parse command line arguments. My program only parses long arguments and all arguments are mandatory. Here is what I have done:

```
getopt --test > /dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 4 ]]; then
    echo "getopt --test failed in this environment."
    exit 1
fi

function quit {
    echo "$1"
    exit 1
}

# Option strings
LONG="producer-dir:,consumer-dir:,username:,password:,url:,kafka-host:,checkpoint-dir:"

# read the options
OPTS=$(getopt --longoptions ${LONG} --name "$0" -- "$@")
if [ $? != 0 ]; then 
    quit "Failed to parse options...exiting."
fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"

# extract options and their arguments into variables.
while true ; do
  case "$1" in
    --producer-dir )
      PRODUCER_DIR="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --consumer-dir )
      CONSUMER_DIR="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --username )
      USERNAME="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --password )
      PASSWORD="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --url )
      URL="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --kafka-host )
      KAFKA_HOST="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --checkpoint-dir )
      CHECKPOINT_DIR="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    -- )
      shift
      break
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Internal error!"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

No matter in which order I pass the arguments, the first one is ignored and the result is empty. The rest of the arguments are parsed as expected.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what is happening is that what you intend to be your first
parameter is being interpreted by `getopt` as an `optstring`. The
beginning of the `getopt` man page lists three synopses. You seem to
be using the second:

```
`getopt [options] [--] optstring parameters`
```

Notice how after the `--` the first item is not `parameters`, but
`optstring`.

While we're at it, I should mention that bash has an internal version
of `getopt`, called `getopts` with the trailing `s`. All other things
being equal, using bash's internal feature should be more efficient.